# WP_Query - foreach array

Tags: arrays, wordpress

In a WP_Query, i need some arrays to be dynamic, when a checkbox-group is checked.

The code so far is:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'hold',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'hold_serie',
        'value' => 'serie3',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ),
       array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
         'options' => array()
       ),
  ),
);

$days = array('man', 'tir', 'ons');

foreach ($days as $value_day) {
  $args['meta_query']['options'] = array(
    'key' => 'hold_day',
    'value' => $value_day,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  );
}
```

I have a checkbox group, which will make the same array as the $days-array().
What I'm hoping to achieve is, that the array with 'key' => 'hold_day' will be repeated three times, and the WP_Query will look at all the posts, that have either "man", "tir" OR "ons".

At this point, the WP_query only takes the post, with the last value in the array, in this case "ons".
If I delete "ons", so the array only have "man" and "tir", it only finds the posts, where "hold_day" = "tir".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You dose not need to use second part of the code.
You can use an array as the value of meta key, but in that case you need to use "IN" in compare field.
Your code should be

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'hold',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'hold_serie',
        'value' => 'serie3',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ),
       array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'key' => 'hold_day',
        'value' => array('man', 'tir', 'ons'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
       ),
  ),
);
```

Try the above code and let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Souvik

With your code, the returned array is empty.
Let me try to maybe explain a little better.

I have a post type called "hold".
There are two posts here:

On with hold_serie = serie3 (lets call it post1)
And a checkbox-array with values "man" & "ons".

Then there is another hold_serie = serie3 (post2)
Where the checkbox array is "tir" & "ons".

So, to make this query, I have made a form, with a checkbox-group, with three checkboxes.
"man", "tir" and "ons".

If I check different checkboxes, I need to see if that value is in the check-box-array of the posts?